# Unable to generate sequence diagram from VS2012 in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, sequence-diagram

I'm trying to generate a sequence diagram from **visual studio ultimate 2012**. But when I click the **Generate Sequence Diagram** after the right clicking, an error appears. The error screenshot is given.

[Error Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAeAI.png)

I need some help about this. And would be very thankful to whom who answers.

Comment: Install VS2015 community it is free. Use MS WebPlatform to update your tools.

Comment: Does "VS2015 community" has support for generating sequence diagrams?